# What does the "State" class constructor look like in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, constructor, state, statefulwidget

What does `super.didChangeDependencies();` do in the following code?

```
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<Contests>(context).fetchAndSetContests().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

I know it should call the `constructor` of the `State` class but I can't find the constructor's definition and don't understand what is the purpose of calling that?

Comment: If you select the State class name in your code in any proper IDE, you should have a right-click menu option to "go to definition".  That will take you to the source code of State. On the mac on VSC, I can also command-click on the name, but that may not be universal.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz: I am looking for `State` class's constructor but still can not find it.

Comment: That's right where I said it would be.  You can also try "go to symbol".  For me on the mac with VSC, that's command-T.  And type "State".  Should take you right to the definition.

Comment: You can view it in the source code at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/135454af32477f815a7525073027a3ff9eff1bfd/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#LL899

Answer (score 0):

From the Flutter docs for [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html):

> Called when a dependency of this State object changes.
>
> For example, if the previous call to build referenced an
> InheritedWidget that later changed, the framework would call this
> method to notify this object about the change.
>
> This method is also called immediately after initState. It is safe to
> call BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType from this method.
>
> Subclasses rarely override this method because the framework always
> calls build after a dependency changes. Some subclasses do override
> this method because they need to do some expensive work (e.g., network
> fetches) when their dependencies change, and that work would be too
> expensive to do for every build.

Comment: I am looking for `State` class's constructor but still can not find it.